# BlackBerry 10 Webworks - Send file in www folder

Tags: facebook, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, jscript

I'm using following invoke code in webworks/bb10 to send a jpg to Facebook. I just get onError called. I think something wrong with the URI?

I've tried turning the sandbox on as well as off but no luck. The jpg file is in /www/img folder as the code shows.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
    function sendCardFB() {

        blackberry.invoke.invoke({
           target: "Facebook",
           action: "bb.action.SHARE",
           type: "image/jpeg",
           uri: "file://"+blackberry.io.home+"/img/wp"+theid+".jpg"
        }, onSuccess, onError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs (https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/facebook.html) you seem to be missing the MIME type